# Disable blury background on UISearchController on tvOS

Tags: uisearchbar, tvos, uisearchcontroller

Since we are using a custom background image throughout our tvOS app, I need the UISearchController to not blur the background. Apparently the `dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation` flag is not available on `UISearchController` under tvOS. Is there any other way to get rid of it?

Comment: You might want to try asking on the dev forum here;
https://forums.developer.apple.com/community/app-frameworks/tvos-sdk AppleTV dev have been answering questions there

Comment: @AndyBoretto FYI: Due to your comment I posted the question in Apple's dev forum as well. But no response either. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23391

Answer (score 7):

Set the `obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation` flag.

```
UISearchController *searchController;
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
```